# what will happen to tasklet execution if interrupt occurs in between

Tags: tasklet

The things I know about tasklet:

1. Tasklet runs with all interrupt enabled.
2. The tasklet runs in interrupt context.
3. It can't be sleep.
4. It runs in atomic way.
5. it has the assurance to be scheduled never late than next tick.

My questions:

1. Since in bottom half all interrupts are enabled, what happened If a tasklet is running and in between any interrupt comes. (If interrupts are disabled during tasklet execution then what is the benefit of tasklet)?
2. Why is the surety that tasklet will always be scheduled upto next tick?
3. Is it correct to say that tasklets are softirq with priority level 0(Hi priority tasklet) and priority level 6(Normal taslet)?

Answer (score 1):

```
*Since in bottom half all interrupts are enabled, what happened If a tasklet is running and in between any interrupt comes. (If interrupts are disabled during tasklet execution then what is the benefit of tasklet)?*
```

From what i understand Tasklet (which is built on soft IRQ) runs in soft IRQ context which essentially means it runs in context of whatever process was running when the process was interrupted by Hard IRQ (so it is borrowing stack) , so an interrupt again would return back to tasklet execution.

```
*Is it correct to say that tasklets are softirq with priority level 0(Hi priority tasklet) and priority level 6(Normal taslet)?*
```

Yes tasklets are essentially wrappers built on Soft IRQ.